# What error is returned by sftp (in unix) if the file is partially uploaded?

Tags: linux, unix, sftp, ksh

I am using the `sftp` command to upload a file to remote server(unix) from local system (linux) in a kshell script. Sometimes the file is partially uploaded(mostly because of empty memory issues in server). How to detect whether a file is fully uploaded or partially uploaded.What is the exact error message that is returned by sftp if the file is partially uploaded? Below is the code used in my shell script.

```
{
        sftp $Remote_srvr << EOF
        cd $TARGET_DIR
        put $path_files/$dump
        bye
EOF
} > $HOME/Proc1/sftp.log 2>&1
stat=$?
echo "sftp exit status is $stat"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in [`sftp`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1?query=sftp&sec=1)'s *batch* mode:

```
cat >/tmp/batch_cmds <<EOF
cd $TARGET_DIR
put $path_files/$dump
bye
EOF

sftp -b /tmp/batch_cmds $Remote_srvr > $HOME/Proc1/sftp.log 2>&1
stat=$?
echo "sftp exit status is $stat"
rm /tmp/batch_cmds
```

In batch mode, `sftp` will abort on the first failure in the sequence of commands. But I am not sure if partial upload is considered as failure of `put` command.

Comment: I have been searching in google, but didn't exactly find how `put` behaves when the file is partially uploaded. Can you please share any resource/links which can give me any idea about what error message can be expected when file is partially uploaded? or is there any way to purposely make a file upload partially? so that i can check how it behaves.

Comment: `sftp` will return a non-zero return code which you can check using `$?`. But I am not sure how `put`/`sftp` will behave in case of a a *partial* file transfer. I can't think of any way to simulate partial transfer to find out the `$?` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
{
    sftp $Remote_srvr << EOF
    cd $TARGET_DIR
    put $path_files/$dump
    bye
EOF
} tee $HOME/Proc1/sftp.log 2>&1 \
| grep -v '^Uploading' \
| grep -v '^sftp>' \
| grep -v '^Connected' > $HOME/Proc1/sftp.filtered.log
```

to look for any anomalies that get printed out. If the filtered log is non-empty then email it to yourself.

However.

I'd actually recommend using a different tool, such as `rsync` which verifies the transfer and returns the error code like you'd expect:

```
rsync -avz $path_files/$dump $Remote_srvr:$TARGET_DIR/./
```

may give you *exactly* what you want.